# Piston heating uniformly

Tags: thermodynamics

In an internal combustion engine, as the fuel-air mixture in the cylinder is ignited, does the piston heat up uniformly as the engine warms up, or is there a spot in the middle of the piston that gets warmer before the rest as the explosions occur?

Comment: I think there is a terminology issue here.  Do you really mean the piston (the moving part that slides back and forth within the cylinder), or do you mean the gas within the cylinder, or the cylinder itself?

Comment: yes I do mean the piston, it was something that a former teacher of mine in an auto tech class mentioned one time and i have been curious about it recently

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The top of the piston heats up first, usually in the center if it is the thinnest part, depending on piston design, and stays hotter than the outer edges. The heat that builds up in the piston is conducted away by the sidewalls of the piston to the cylinder wall through a thin layer of oil. So the sides remain cooler than the top. I have seen air cooled motorcycle pistons, ran in extreme conditions, with a hole melted in the top center.

Answer (score 0):

The piston is cast from aluminum which means that its top is good at diffusing any hotspots away quickly. the temperature of the pistons rises uniformly as the engine comes up to operating temperature.

Note also that the underside of the piston is subject to oil being splashed up against it from the oil sump, which carries away heat and also tends to minimize hotspots.